# Mutually exclusive booleans in javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object with 3 booleans:

```
var obj = {};
obj.isPrimary = true;
obj.isPromotion = false;
obj.isSocial = false;
```

Only one of these can be true, there can never be a case where more than 1 is true.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use getters and setters that toggle the properties appropriately. You'll still be able to update the values directly though.

Comment: I say the easier way would be to implement a class, and getter & setter for both variables. Changing one would automatically change the other.

Comment: Is it also possible to just do this in a function?  For example, setting one would just change the others to false.

Answer (score 2):

Using a getter / setter should do the trick:

```js
var obj = {
    set isPrimary(bool){
        this.Primary = bool;
        if(bool){
            this.Promotion = this.Social = false;
        }
    },
    set isSocial(bool){
        this.Social = bool;
        if(bool){
            this.Promotion = this.Primary = false;
        }
    },
    set isPromotion(bool){
        this.Promotion = bool;
        if(bool){
            this.Primary = this.Social = false;
        }
    },
    get isPrimary(){   return this.Primary;   },
    get isSocial(){    return this.Social;    },
    get isPromotion(){ return this.Promotion; }
}

obj.isPrimary = true;
obj.isSocial = true;
obj.isPromotion = true;

alert(obj.isPrimary + ' ' + obj.isSocial + ' ' + obj.isPromotion);
// false false true (So only `obj.isPromotion` is true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) something like:

```
 Object.defineProperty(obj, 'isPrimary', {
    get: function(){ 
       return  !this.isPromotion && !this.isSocial; //<-- Your logic goes here.
    }
 });
```

Of course the logic behind toggling this option on and off it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are your friend. They prevent that somebody can fiddle with the internal state.

```
function createPropObj() {
 var props = 0;

 return {
  get isPrimary() { return props === 1; },
  set isPrimary(val) { if (val) { props = 1; }; },
  get isPromotion() { return props === 2; },
  set isPromotion(val) { if (val) { props = 2; }; },
  get isSocial() { return props === 4; },
  set isSocial(val) { if (val) { props = 4; }; }
 }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
> var test = createPropObj();
undefined
> test.isPrimary = true;
true
> test.isPromotion = true;
true
> test.isPrimary
false
```

Comment: What happened to `3`? :P

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe he wants to change his logic some day. With 1, 2, 4, 8, ... he can use the number as flag field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bitmasks really isn't what the OP is looking for at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this with a function like this

```
function createToggleValues() {
    var options = {
            "primary": 1,
            "promotion": 2,
            "social": 4
        },
        value = 0;
    return {
        "set": function(name) {
            value = options[name];
        },
        "is": function(name) {
            return (value & options[name]) === options[name];
        }
    }
};

var togglable = createToggleValues();

togglable.set("primary");
console.log(togglable.is("primary"));
// true
```

If you require more options to be added, then you might want to simply extend the `options` object with new values and the next multiple of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object responsible for allowing a single flag to be true at a time. That would relieve your `obj` from implementing that logic. In the example below, `SingleTrueFlagGroup` holds onto a collection of flags, allowing a single one to be true at a time. Your `obj` can then double-dispatch on an instance of this object to get the job done.

The advantage of a similar implementation is that adding and removing flags becomes trivial.

```
var flags = ['isPrimary', 'isPromotion', 'isSocial'],
    obj = {
        _flags: new SingleTrueFlagGroup(flags)
    };

flags.forEach(function (flag) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, flag, {
        get: function () { return this._flags.get(flag); },
        set: function (value) { this._flags.set(flag, value); }
    });
});


obj.isPrimary = true;
obj.isPromotion = true;

console.log(obj.isPrimary); //false
console.log(obj.isPromotion); //true




function SingleTrueFlagGroup(flags) {
    this._flags = {};

    (flags || []).forEach(this.add.bind(this));
}

SingleTrueFlagGroup.prototype = {
    constructor: SingleTrueFlagGroup,

    set: function (flagToSet, value) {
        var flags = this._flags;

        (flags[flagToSet] = !!value) && Object.keys(flags).forEach(function (flag) {
            if (flag !== flagToSet) flags[flag] = false;
        });
    },

    get: function (flag) { return this._flags[flag]; },

    add: function (flag) { this._flags[flag] = false; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers may work, but they seem over-engineered*.

If the values are exclusive, you should represent them in a single property, not three separate booleans:

```js
obj.type = 'primary' // or 'promotion' or 'social'
```

Assignment among different values is inherently exclusive, since the variable can only hold one value at a time.

Or if you don't like [magic strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings), you can use an **enum**eration of defined values:

```js
const TYPE_PRIMARY = 0
const TYPE_PROMOTION = 1
const TYPE_SOCIAL = 2

...

obj.type = TYPE_PRIMARY
```

Comment: *A fair retort is to point out that the other answers solve the problem exactly in the way that it is originally posed. To their credit, I mildly loathe answers/comments that challenge the reasons for the original question. Often the developer knows why they want to do something a certain way. Still, we can assume that less experienced questioners would be happy to receive some wisdom from an elder if their question is misguided. In this case, the other answers provide adequate solutions if the object's schema cannot be changed. But if it can, a single property is far more elegant.